# java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted while writing a Big file in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera

I am reading data from SQL server about 9 million rows and inserting it into a table already existing in my datalake(Parquet)

This process worked with less data around 1 million.

I am using the basic read write only for sql server :

[image]

My Spark Submit looks like this:

[image]

My Pyspark Config :

[image]

I have tried repartition and increasing the memory to 15 but still the same issue..

java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted

Sorry but i dont have access to full logs

Comment: can you get the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're reading data such way, it's really only one core is used, as JDBC connector doesn't automatically parallelize reads until it explicitly configured to do so. So most probably the connection is timed out during the read operation.

You need to look to the [JDBC connector options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) like, `partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, etc. that will split the reads into multiple operations. (maybe also look to the `fetchsize`, etc.)

Comment: Hi Alex i tried the fix on this page (and it worked but just like the auther i also dont know why)   https://thespark.dev/spark-java-io-ioexception-stream-is-corrupted/

Comment: I'm glad that it's working for you. Anyway, I recommend to look to the partioning of your queries

Comment: Do u have any idea about that config in the link?

Comment: This option disables the use of the readahead on the spill reader: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/util/collection/unsafe/sort/UnsafeSorterSpillReader.java#L73 - I suspect that it's trying to load block of data, and somehow not aligned to the compression block boundary, or something like this...